# Django ulr does not accept query string

Tags: django

I have a view in Django that redirects a user to some url with aditional query string:

```
return redirect('search/?print_id='+str(pk))
```

In my urls.py, the url pattern looks like this:

```
path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
```

And the problem is when Django tries to redirect, I get the following error:

`Reverse for 'search/?print_id=36' not found. 'search/?print_id=36' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

How can I modify the url pattern to accept a query string?

Comment: When you are redirecting You need to pass "full" app url from souce urls, so if you have app books, then you should pass your url as "/books/search/?print_id=13"

Answer (score 0):

`redirect` will try to look for a view with that name. You should work with a :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, QueryDict
from django.urls import reverse

# …

qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
qd['print_id'] = pk
return HttpResponseRedirect(f"{reverse('search')}?{qd.urlencode()}")
```